# Swift class to interact with Interface Builder via IBOutlet

Tags: xcode, class, swift, xcode6

Good evening all,

I'm slowly working through my first OS X app. I have been having a hard time getting my Swift class to interact with an NSPopUpButton. Just to make sure I was doing it right, I created a new project and successfully erased all entries and entered text into the NSPopUpButton via AppDelegate. However, as soon as I try to move the same functionality to my own class, I can't even get the IBOutlet connection across to the new class.

Is a particular subclass type required of a new class to work properly with interface builder?

Here is a screenshot of the class I have created, as well as AppDelegate where I am trying to call the function belonging to this class.

[image: imgur.com/3H7oXRz]

Finally, here is the IB element in question, should I be able to select my own class under the 'Custom Class' inspector?

[image: imgur.com/3H7oXRz,24uE4rl#1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an iOS developer, but I would imagine the same principles would apply to your situation. 
A ViewController class and an interface created in interface builder are two seperate things. While it may appear that they are connected via an iboutlet, they are actually independent and one can be instantiated without the other. 
Currently, you are only creating an instance of your ViewController class in your App Delegate - and that's all. The system has no idea that your xib even exists! The outlets will only be connected once your app connects your xib to your ViewController class. 
How do we do this? It's actually quite simple. Instead of instantiating our view controller like this:

```
let viewcontroller = ViewController()
```

We would connect our view controller to our xib in the instantiation:

```
let viewcontroller = ViewController(nibName: "MainWindow", bundle: NSBundle().mainBundle)
```

The `nibName` is telling the system the file name of your xib, and the `NSBundle().mainBundle` is telling the system where to look for the xib. 
This will all only work if your xib has been assigned a custom class, like you mentioned. In your xib in interface builder, select the entire view controller. Then, in the custom class inspector type in the name of your ViewController class (in your case: ViewController - it should autocomplete). This will make sure your outlets are connected. 
And you should be set up!! Let me know if you have any more problems come up. 
Good luck!

***EDIT:***
This replaces the first part of my answer, however the part about hooking things up in Storyboard remains true. Upon reconsidering, I've believe I've realized that we are only creating the view controller, and not adding it to our view. Despite this, I believe we can take a short cut solution by adding one method to your view controller subclass (the one we set in the Storyboard). Start typing in `viewDidLoad`, and it should autocomplete. Type in `super.viewDidLoad()` at the beginning of the method. After that, type `self.listUpdate()`. This should work if the classes are hooked up correctly in Storyboard. This means you can delete the variables you created in the App Delegate.

**Reference**: You might also find Apple's documentation on creating a view controller handy (it's in Objective C online, but can be easily converted to Swift - it's the concept that counts): [NSViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005253-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I hadn't even thought to pass any arguments when initializing the class. When I implement the arguments I get the following error when I attempt to build the app: 'Extra argument 'bundle' in call'. I tried removing the second argument altogether but naturally it didn't like that. I also tried making the second argument simply 'bundle: nil' as suggested in Apple's documentation which searches for the bundle in the mainBundle by default. This gave me the error 'Incorrect argument label in call (Have 'MainMenu:bundle:' expected 'nibName:bundle:')'

Comment: It sounds like you might have typed the order of your initializer wrong. Did you type it exactly like this: `ViewController(nibName: "MainWindow", bundle: NSBundle().mainBundle)`? Remember the name on the left side of the `:` is the argument name and the name on the right is your value

Comment: Okay, I reverted the code to your original statement, just replacing NSBundle().mainBundle with nil and it passes that line fine now but then can't find the method in my ViewController class.

The error: http://imgur.com/irU0dsD,3ZXq3MF

My class: http://imgur.com/irU0dsD,3ZXq3MF#1

Comment: Ah. This is because that initializer creates an optional - optionals must be unpacked before you can use them. To unpack an optional, add an exclamation after your variable like so: `viewcontroller!.listUpdate()`

Comment: I have implemented the change and it builds correctly but still doesn't update the window at all.

Just to check it all over, I currently have the MainMenu.xib with a single window with one popup button. I have file's owner set to ViewController (my class). The window and button all have default settings. I have created a View Controller object of class ViewController within the same xib. 

The following screenshot shows the connections that have been made: View Controller Object --> View, Window/View/Button --> ViewController Class. 
http://imgur.com/7JfDXBb

Does this appear right?

Comment: Is your class being created at all? Is the method being called? Try creating a breakpoint at the `var word = "Hello"` and see if it gets called

Comment: I tried inserting breakpoints at practically every line of my class and nothing is ever called. Am I missing some important step in setting up my class?

Comment: Hmm. This is taking longer than I anticipated! Try adding a breakpoint where you create the view controller and check the logs to see if its being set

Comment: I created the breakpoint however it never reaches it. The program launches and displays the interface that I created in IB. However the program won't stop at any point for a breakpoint when I create the view controller, nor even for the applicationDidFinishLaunching() line in app delegate. For the moment however I appreciate all of the help you have provided thus far! I am no doubt a long way off from finding a solution and obviously I am lacking the knowledge required for the problem at hand. I won't keep you any longer but thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: I see! Let me try one more thing before we call it quits, because I don't like to see an unsolved problem. Check my edited answer

Comment: That was nothing short of a miracle! My test program finally spits out the updated popup button! Thank you ever so much! Now, I've just got to translate what I've learned there over to the full program I've started. Thanks again, have a great weekend!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad we could get it working. Best of luck to you and have a great weekend as well :)

Comment: A final update if you're interested. I quickly managed to re-create the same changes you suggested in my original app and finally got something working!!! It will eventually function as a basic serial interface that will send GCode commands to an Arduino driven laser cutter I've built. http://imgur.com/uBusJCM Thanks again, it's ever so rewarding to finally see something work the way I want it to!

Comment: I hope I am not going out of scope, it took me a full day to finally reach your answer and be able to understand how to display a window. I'm a .Net developer and I do write android apps, and concept is completely different than Swift for Mac. Can you please reference some good resources to help me get started? Another question would be: for bundle in your answer code snippet, why exactly we should tell it where is the xib file? shouldn't it takes it project root by default (by giving: bundle: nil)?

Comment: @OmarBizreh The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:) for the parameters tell us why we specify `mainBundle()`: `"The bundle in which to search for the nib file. If you specify nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle."` We specify the `mainBundle()` just because if we don't it will be specified anyway. Would you like references for getting started in Swift for OSX or iOS?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my noob question. I'd like references for both please. and while searching I've also seen that using Storyboards are more recommended? As a new starter which do you recommend me to start with?

Comment: No problem! We're all learning - I'm 15 and I was in your position not too long ago :). I really like storyboards and I try to use them whenever I can - however, it is not always possible to use them. You may need to embed a view controller into another for custom behavior, and this cannot be accomplished in a storyboard (you will know when it won't work). I'm also a big fan of [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com), a ubiquitous site for ios and osx dev. They have fantastic resources on anything you need - just search `what you want to know` + `wenderlich` or `wenderlich tutorial`.

Comment: @OmarBizreh See above - had to add another comment to mention you due to character limits.

Comment: @OmarBizreh [Great tutorial on Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, checked that website and it does contain lots of swift stuff! I guess I was lucky to end up here, was pulling my hair out lol.

Comment: Haha I've definitely been there! Best of luck and feel free to contact me if you have any questions. @OmarBizreh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70010/discussion-between-omarbizreh-and-dcgoss).